# Overlapping address error in Packet Tracer (subinterfaces)

Tags: networking

I have two subnets. 172.24.99.64/25 and 172.24.99.192/27. for some reason when i input 172.24.99.190 255.255.255.128 in g0/0.10 and then input 172.24.99.222 255.255.255.224 in g0/0.20, it says 172.24.99.192 overlaps with GigabitEthernet0/0.10. what can i do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

They do overlap. Your IP ranges are 172.24.99.129 - 172.24.99.254 and 172.24.99.193 - 172.24.99.222. Chance your classes so there's no common address space.

Putting 172.24.99.64/25 as /27 should do if you don't have more than the number of IPs the class can provide.